# Not able to access some websites after updating Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04?

Tags: networking, 15.04, 14.10

I just updated my Ubuntu from 14.10 to 15.04.

After that I am not able to open some websites,for example Flipkart.com, Naukri.com etc.

All these sites I am able to open in Mobile by connecting to the same network.

For naukri.com I am getting this error.

```
Request Timeout
The server timed out while waiting for the browser's request
Reference #2.6576cd17.1441305291.0
```

please help!

Comment: are you able to ping  ` ping 8.8.8.8 ` if not then means your DNS is not configured and you have do setting of DNS or you are not connected .